# Jeditable displays entire HTML document as replacement for the editable field after trigger/submit

Tags: jeditable, inline-editing

I am using jeditable and had it working very weird.

after editing the editable field and submits it instead of printing the new content it displays the entire document window in the textbox(placeholder of editable content).

question: from the example where the author used save.php. what was the content of save.php?
is it necessary to send the result on a php file?? can't an HTML file work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe within the comments box at the bottom of the author's main page - somebody has kindly provided a version of the save.php file for people to use and modify as needed.

The save.php file is used to actually save the values of the editable field/s.  Without it, nothing would happen to the data and it would reset to the default text if the page is refreshed.

Options instead of a php file could be:

- Saving the text/select changes to a Cookie
- Using another server side methos such as asp, jsp, rails or .NET to process the saving of the changes.

an html page is a static page with no processing facility per say to communicate with the website server, so no.. html is not suitable for such a need.

Answer (score 0):

Saving script must return the string you want to display on page after editing. You are now returning full html page.

Source of for all demofiles can be found from [GitHub](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable).